# adding google analytics via echo or between <php> tags

Tags: functions, google-analytics

I'm adding the google analytics script in `functions.php`, and I was wondereing if there any concerns about adding it with a function like:

```
function add_google_analytics() { ?>
    <script> GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE </script>
<?php }
```

vs a function like

```
function add_google_analytics() {
    echo "<script>GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're quotes are escaped to render the final code correctly, you should be fine either way. That just a matter of preference.

If you go with the first route, you'll be able to migrate your scripts to an external source with very little extra effort. The second way can get a little annoying if you need to unslash quotes.

Comment: thanks. I don't believe I'll need to escape any quotes in the analytics script, but that's helpful to know.